# Is there a way for the Entry widget to not mimic the Checkbutton's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Right off the bat here is my code so far (please ignore the variable names. I am still learning how to use Python):

```
root = Tk()

testvariable = 0

bruh = 0

test = Checkbutton(root, variable = testvariable, )
test.pack()

test1 = Entry(root,textvariable = bruh, text = "0", width = 4)
test1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I notice that when I select the Checkbutton to turn it off or on, the Entry widget automatically changes its value to whatever the Checkbutton's value is. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting variables in tkinter make sure to use the built-in types (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables).

For the Entry widget you can directly use the get method to assign its value to a variable. As for the Checkbutton widget, make sure to assign it an "IntVar" type to correctly deal with its value passing. I've demonstrated how to do both of the above in the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

checkbox_var = tk.IntVar()
testvariable = 0
bruh = 0

test = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=checkbox_var)
test.pack()

test1 = tk.Entry(root)
test1.pack()

def testOutput():
    testvariable = checkbox_var.get()
    bruh = test1.get()

    print("Checkbox is", testvariable)
    print("Entry is", bruh)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Test Button", command=testOutput)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

They mimic each other because both of their `textvariable` attributes are the same value. The short answer is to give them each different values for `textvariable`.

Also, you should be setting that attribute to an instance of a tkinter variable such as `StringVar` or `IntVar`. However you rarely need to use that attribute with `Entry` widgets, since the widget itself gives you methods for getting and setting the value.

Comment: For clarification, the "textvariable" is not the issue, it appears to be duplicated, but that is not the issue in this case. This is a glitch in tkinter that I think is related to the named arguments. I tested this by changing the variable names, and used class members as well to see if that would change the result. With all of the tests, the Checkbutton widget would still write into the Entry widget. 

The bug is discussed in further detail here, https://bugs.python.org/issue38898.